# caching pictures in JSF page

Tags: html, caching, jsf-2

Working on some JSF 2.0 project. Have form for adding picture for new/existing user. Can't see a new added picture without refreshing the page (*.xhtml). I tried to put regular:

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"> 
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"> 
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

But it not helps.

How can I disable page caching?

Comment: Please post your xhtml file. Its not the browser cache that is important here. You need to update the component that displays your image after you add a new picture.

Comment: for showing image I'm using HTML `<img src="">` tag...

Comment: okay, but still it does not help in understanding how you are updating  the image after adding a new picture.

Comment: I have this code:    `<object data="#{userBean.resourceUrl}/#{o.pic}.png" id="UserPictureThumb_${o.userID}" width="72" height="72"><img src="resources/images/AddUserImg-Icon.png" width="72" height="72" /></object>` and I'm changing the source (data) of `<object>` with different pictures with same names. It doesn't refreshes without ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML `<meta http-equiv>` tags are **ignored** when the page is been served over HTTP. The `<meta http-equiv>` tags are only interpreted when the page is by the enduser been saved to the local disk file system and then opened from it by a `file://` URL.

You need to set those headers on the *real* HTTP response instead. Easiest way is to use a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which basically does

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

*(note that your original `Cache-Control` header was incomplete, the above example is the proper usage)*

You could map the on the URL pattern of the specific page, but you could also consider to map it on all dynamic pages generated by JSF.